# The proof of Fundamental Theorem of Finitely Generated Abelian Groups

Tags: abstract-algebra

I want to prove the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, but I could not do that, also I could not find any hint. Could you please give some hints or details of the proof?

Comment: Couldn't you find an online source with a full proof?

Comment: Know anything about modules?

Comment: The textbook: "Judson -- Abstract Algebra - Theory and Applications (2017)" is made freely available by the author. Here's a link:
$$$$
$\quad$http://abstract.ups.edu/download/aata-20170805.pdf
$$$$
Section 13.1 has a complete proof of the theorem in question.

Comment: @quasi The current version of the textbook does not seem to have a proof. It only proves the theorem for finite groups, not finitely generated ones.

Comment: @Bill: You're right, that text only analyzes the case of finite abelian groups. For the finitely generated case, see Theorem 1.54 of the text: "Milne -- Group Theory", made freely available by the author. Here's a link: https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/GTc.pdf